# Parsing WSDL complexType and choice with PHP/SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Below is a request I am sending to the SOAP webservice. According to the WSDL, when I am using PostTransaction it allows 1 instance of 'CheckDetailEntries' per transaction.

```
<s:complexType name="PostTransactionRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestHeader" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestHeader" />

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckDetailEntries" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfChoice1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckHeaderRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:CheckHeaderRequest" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderTypeNumber" type="s:unsignedByte" />
        </s:sequence>
```

It says that CheckDetailEntries is type="tns:ArrayOfChoice1" . How do I put in the array of choices? Currently I Initiate CheckDetailEntries via `$request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries = new CheckDetailEntries();` which works for one item, but when I try to do two items I am getting errors. Am I missing something?

My PHP code:

```
$request = new PostTransaction();
        $request->REQ = new PostTransactionRequest();
        $request->REQ->RequestHeader = new RequestHeader();

        $request->REQ->RequestHeader->InterfaceVersion = $this->GetVersion($clientName)->data->interfaceVersion;
        $request->REQ->RequestHeader->ClientName = $clientName;

        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries = new CheckDetailEntries();

        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem = new MenuItem();
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->ReferenceEntry = "Item";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->Count = "1";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->Price = "1.67";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->ItemNumber = "112001";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->PriceLevel = "1";
        // Here is the problem. How can I have multiple Items?
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem = new MenuItem();
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->ReferenceEntry = "Item";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->Count = "1";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->Price = "1.67";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->ItemNumber = "125004";
        $request->REQ->CheckDetailEntries->MenuItem->->MenuItem->PriceLevel = "1";
```

**The WSDL(had to strip some out for it to fit in the body 30,000 char requirement):**

```
      <s:complexType name="RequestHeader">

        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterfaceVersion" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ClientName" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RawPMSSendResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RawPMSSendResponse" type="tns:RawPMSSendResponse" />

          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>

      <s:element name="PostTransaction">

        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="REQ" type="tns:PostTransactionRequest" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="PostTransactionRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestHeader" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestHeader" />

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckDetailEntries" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfChoice1" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckHeaderRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:CheckHeaderRequest" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderTypeNumber" type="s:unsignedByte" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfChoice1">
        <s:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MenuItem" nillable="true" type="tns:MenuItem" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ServiceCharge" nillable="true" type="tns:ServiceCharge" />

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CreditCardTender" nillable="true" type="tns:CreditCardTender" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EnhancedServiceCharge" nillable="true" type="tns:EnhancedServiceCharge" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Information" nillable="true" type="tns:Information" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Condiment" nillable="true" type="tns:Condiment" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CashTender" nillable="true" type="tns:CashTender" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EnhancedTender" nillable="true" type="tns:EnhancedTender" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EnhancedMenuItem" nillable="true" type="tns:EnhancedMenuItem" />
        </s:choice>
      </s:complexType>

      <s:complexType name="MenuItem">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReferenceEntry" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Count" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Price" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemNumber" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PriceLevel" type="s:unsignedByte" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Seat" nillable="true" type="s:unsignedByte" />
        </s:sequence>

      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="EnhancedMenuItem">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="tns:MenuItem">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InterfaceNumber" type="s:int" />
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Service" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ServiceData" nillable="true">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">

                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:any />
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>

      <s:complexType name="Condiment">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="tns:MenuItem">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Level" nillable="true" type="s:unsignedByte" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>

      <s:complexType name="ServiceCharge">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReferenceEntry" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Count" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Price" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemNumber" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Item" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemChoiceType" type="tns:ItemChoiceType" />
        </s:sequence>

      </s:complexType>


      <s:element name="PostTransactionResponse">
        <s:complexType>

          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PostTransactionResponse" type="tns:PostTransactionResponse" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="PostTransactionResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OperationResult" nillable="true" type="tns:OperationResult" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderAccepted" type="s:boolean" />

          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CredCardAuthCode" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckHeaderResponse" type="tns:CheckHeaderResponse" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PMSResponse" type="tns:ArrayOfString" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CheckHeaderResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckNumber" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckGuid" type="s:string" />

          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckID" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GuestCount" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EmployeeNumber" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Cashier" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UwsNumber" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckOpenTime" type="s:dateTime" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckClosedTime" type="s:dateTime" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderTypeNumber" type="s:unsignedByte" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckAutofireTime" type="s:dateTime" />

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckSubtotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckTaxTotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckAutogratuityTotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckOtherTotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckPaymentTotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckAmountDueTotal" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberOfCheckDetails" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GuestInformation" type="tns:GuestInformation" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckStatus" type="tns:ArrayOfBoolean" />

        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>


      <s:element name="HeartBeatResponse">

        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="bool" type="s:boolean" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetOpenCheckList">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>

            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="REQ" type="tns:GetOpenCheckSLUListRequest" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="GetOpenCheckSLUListRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestHeader" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestHeader" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>

      <s:element name="GetOpenCheckListResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetOpenCheckSLUListResponse" type="tns:GetOpenCheckSLUListResponse" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="GetOpenCheckSLUListResponse">
        <s:sequence>

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="index" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="num_entries" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OpenCheckDetails" type="tns:ArrayOfOpenCheckSLUEntry" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OperationResult" nillable="true" type="tns:OperationResult" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfOpenCheckSLUEntry">
        <s:sequence>

          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="OpenCheckSLUEntry" nillable="true" type="tns:OpenCheckSLUEntry" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="OpenCheckSLUEntry">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="emp_status" type="s:short" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Autofire_Check" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="tbl" type="s:int" />

          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="grp" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="number" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="check_open_Time" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="amt_due_ttl" type="s:decimal" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="check_empl" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="guid" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="AddToCheck">

        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="REQ" type="tns:PostTransactionRequest" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Check_Guid" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="AddToCheckResponse">
        <s:complexType>

          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PostTransactionResponse" type="tns:PostTransactionResponse" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CalculateTotalsAddToCheck">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="REQ" type="tns:CalculateTotalsRequest" />

            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckGUID" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CalculateTotalsAddToCheckResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CalculateTotalsResponse" type="tns:CalculateTotalsExResponse" />
          </s:sequence>

        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PostTransactionSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PostTransaction" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PostTransactionSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PostTransactionResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CalculateTotalsSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CalculateTotals" />

  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="TransactionServices6Soap">
    <wsdl:operation name="RawPMSSend">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RawPMSSendSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RawPMSSendSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostTransaction">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:PostTransactionSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:PostTransactionSoapOut" />

    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotals">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CalculateTotalsSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CalculateTotalsSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotalsEx">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CalculateTotalsExSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CalculateTotalsExSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="SimInquiry">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:SimInquirySoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:SimInquirySoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetVersion">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetVersionSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetVersionSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="HeartBeat">

      <wsdl:input message="tns:HeartBeatSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:HeartBeatSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOpenCheckList">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetOpenCheckListSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetOpenCheckListSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AddToCheck">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:AddToCheckSoapIn" />

      <wsdl:output message="tns:AddToCheckSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotalsAddToCheck">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CalculateTotalsAddToCheckSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CalculateTotalsAddToCheckSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="TransactionServices6Soap" type="tns:TransactionServices6Soap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="RawPMSSend">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/RawPMSSend" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="PostTransaction">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/PostTransaction" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>



    <wsdl:operation name="GetOpenCheckList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/GetOpenCheckList" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="AddToCheck">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/AddToCheck" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>



  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="TransactionServices6Soap12" type="tns:TransactionServices6Soap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="RawPMSSend">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/RawPMSSend" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostTransaction">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/PostTransaction" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotals">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/CalculateTotals" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotalsEx">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/CalculateTotalsEx" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="SimInquiry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/SimInquiry" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetVersion">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/GetVersion" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="HeartBeat">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/HeartBeat" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetOpenCheckList">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/GetOpenCheckList" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AddToCheck">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/AddToCheck" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CalculateTotalsAddToCheck">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.micros.com/pos/les/TransactionServices/CalculateTotalsAddToCheck" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>

        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="TransactionServices6">
    <wsdl:port name="TransactionServices6Soap" binding="tns:TransactionServices6Soap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/TransactionServices/TransactionServices6.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="TransactionServices6Soap12" binding="tns:TransactionServices6Soap12">

      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/TransactionServices/TransactionServices6.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: did u problem got solved can u post ur soultion that worked for others like me please :)